# MongoDB - update arrays in object array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I have the following structure:

```
    {
      data: [
        {pos:"0",
         moreData: ["a", "b"]
        },
        {pos:"1",
         moreData: ["a", "c"]
        },
    ]}
```

I would like to update the above structure with an update. I would like to add a letter to moreData where pos=1. This is how it should look like at the end:

```
    {
      data: [
        {pos:"0",
         moreData: ["a", "b"]
        },
        {pos:"1",
         moreData: ["a", "c", "d"]
        },
    ]}
```

I am doing this, at the moment: (using mongoose, but whatever would be fine)

```
    model.update({"data.pos":"1"},
                 { $push: {data:{ pos:"1", moreData:["d"] } } },
                 { safe: true, upsert: false }, function(err){
    });
```

All I'm getting is a duplicated "pos":"1" with a "moreData" containing only the new element "d".
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you need to push to the correct array element. You can either do this directly by dot notation and index value or by using the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator:

```js
 model.update(
     {"data.pos": "1" },
     { "$push": { "data.$.moreData": "d" } },
     function(err, numAffected) {

 })
```

That should match the selected index of the "data" array in order to perform the update. Beware though, you have nested arrays and you would not be able to match and update an item in the inner array. See the positional operator documentation for this

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I've tried your solution, but it doesn't add anything to the db.
I think, as you mentioned already, is that you can't use $ for nested arrays.

Comment: @user881387 is your actual data different from the question? This does work on the data as you have presented it. You can use $ for nested arrays but it only matches the **first** element, and that is all that is needed in this case. It only becomes a problem when you want to change something the the "c" element in "moreData" to "b". There you cannot match **two** array indexes. But there is nothing wrong with a $push operation like above.

Comment: @user881387 Not the best thing try and post in comments as it is very hard to read. But you seem to be asking something different from your question. The answer is given to your question, if you have another question then post another. The statement given **will** add the "d" element to your array under the conditions given.

Comment: My bad....
I was actually doing { "$push": { "data.$.pos": "d" } }

It works!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your data structure, `{"data.pos": 1}` selects the whole document (so $push doesn't act as expected):

```
> db.demo.find({"data.pos": "1"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("533a850fd15748cc2dc1a17f"), "data" : [  {   "pos" : "0",    "moreData" : [  "a",    "b" ] },    {   "pos" : "1",    "moreData" : [  "a",    "c" ] } ] }
```

Try adding an id or something to your document:

```
> db.demo.find({"id": "foo"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("533a85c9d15748cc2dc1a180"), "id" : "foo", "data" : [    {   "pos" : "0",    "moreData" : [  "a",    "b" ] },    {   "pos" : "1",    "moreData" : [  "a",    "c" ] } ] }
> db.demo.update({"id": "foo"}, {"$push": { "data" : { "pos": "2", "moreData": ["c", "d"]}}})
> db.demo.find({"id": "foo"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("533a85c9d15748cc2dc1a180"), "data" : [  {   "pos" : "0",    "moreData" : [  "a",    "b" ] },    {   "pos" : "1",    "moreData" : [  "a",    "c" ] },    {   "pos" : "2",    "moreData" : [  "c",    "d" ] } ], "id" : "foo" }
```

Seems to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. As you suggest in your solution, you are adding a new "pos" to the first level array. What I would like to add is a new data to the "moreData" array of an existing "pos".

Comment: Check out if Neil's solution works. Nested arrays in mongoDB can be messy (I would think whether there could be a way around it!)